# Webscraping RequestGet from Airbnb not working properly

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

This query is returning 0 or 20 randomly every time i run it. Yesterday when i loop through the pages i always get 20 and I am able to scrape through 20 listings and 15 pages. But now, I can't run my code properly because sometimes the listings return 0.

I tried adding headers in the request get and time sleep (5-10s random) before each request but am still facing the same issue. Tried connecting to hotspot to change my IP but am still facing the same issue. Anyone understand why?

```
import time
from random import randint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests #to connect to url

airbnb_url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/s/Mayrhofen--Austria/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&date_picker_type=calendar&query=Mayrhofen%2C%20Austria&place_id=ChIJbzLYLzjdd0cRDtGuTzM_vt4&checkin=2021-02-06&checkout=2021-02-13&adults=4&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=autocomplete_click'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(airbnb_url).content, 'html.parser')
listings = soup.find_all('div', '_8s3ctt')
print(len(listings))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems AirBnB returns 2 versions of the page. One "normal" HTML and other where the listings are stored inside `<script>`. To parse the `<script>` version of page you can use next example:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def find_listing(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if "__typename" in d and d["__typename"] == "DoraListingItem":
            yield d["listing"]
        else:
            for v in d.values():
                yield from find_listing(v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            yield from find_listing(v)


airbnb_url = "https://www.airbnb.com/s/Mayrhofen--Austria/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&date_picker_type=calendar&query=Mayrhofen%2C%20Austria&place_id=ChIJbzLYLzjdd0cRDtGuTzM_vt4&checkin=2021-02-06&checkout=2021-02-13&adults=4&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=autocomplete_click"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(airbnb_url).content, "html.parser")
listings = soup.find_all("div", "_8s3ctt")

if len(listings):
    # normal page:
    print(len(listings))
else:
    # page that has listings stored inside <script>:

    data = json.loads(soup.select_one("#data-deferred-state").contents[0])
    for i, l in enumerate(find_listing(data), 1):
        print(i, l["name"])
```

Prints (when returned the `<script>` version):

```
1 Mariandl (MHO103) for 36 persons.
2 central and friendly! For Families and Friends
3 Sonnenheim for 5 persons.
4 MO's Apartments
5 MO's Apartments
6 Beautiful home in Mayrhofen with 3 Bedrooms
7 Quaint Apartment in Finkenberg near Ski Lift
8 Apartment 2 Villa Daringer (5 pax.)
9 Modern Apartment in Schwendau with Garden
10 Holiday flats Dornau, Mayrhofen
11 Maple View
12 Laubichl Lodge by Apart Hotel Therese
13 Haus Julia - Apartment Edelweiß Mayrhofen
14 Melcherhof,
15 Rest coke
16 Vacation home Traudl
17 Luxurious Apartment near Four Ski Lifts in Mayrhofen
18 Apartment 2 60m² for 2-4 persons "Binder"
19 Apart ZEMMGRUND, 4-9 persons in Mayrhofen/Tirol
20 Apartment Ahorn View
```

---

EDIT: To print `lat`, `lng`:

```py
...

    for i, l in enumerate(find_listing(data), 1):
        print(i, l["name"], l["lat"], l["lng"])
```

Prints:

```
1 Mariandl (MHO103) for 36 persons. 47.16522 11.85723
2 central and friendly! For Families and Friends 47.16209 11.859691
3 Sonnenheim for 5 persons. 47.16809 11.86694
4 MO's Apartments 47.166969 11.863186

...
```

Comment: Thank you. This means my code will only work on HTML page where the information is not embedded in the script tag? Is there any way to extract the listing with its lat,long? I am able to see some lat,long info in the script tag but am not sure how to extract it.

Comment: @WJSG To get lat, lng you can use `"lat"`, `"lng"` keys (see my edit). For other keys you can do `print(l)`, there are many of them.

Comment: Thank you!! It works but I am trying to understand what you are doing. How do you even know 1) to reach 'soup.select_one("#data-deferred-state").contents[0])' and 2)can you roughly explain what is find_listing doing? It seems like a recursive function. Sorry I don't have a lot of experience in coding.

Comment: @WJSG I examined the output from `print(soup)` and searched where the data are stored (they are under `<script id="data-deferred-state">` tag).  The function to find listing is recursive - because the data is deeply nested and from the brief examination it changes a lot. This recursive function doesn't depend on "depth" of the data dictionary.

Comment: I see. Sorry when i tried to loop through the different pages using the offset, I kept getting the same 20 listings from page 1. Do you have any idea why? For each loop, I have checked that the url used is different. Edited:Sorry my mistake, i forgot to change one of the variable

Comment: Would you have anyone idea how I can get from reviews for each listing? I managed to get the URL for each of the individual listing. But when I go into the URL, I was not able to see the reviews in the page source but am able to see it in the elements. I am not sure how to extract the review from the elements. They are all contained in the span tag which is not available in the page source.